# Customizing Firefox Shortcuts

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser-addons

I would like to be able to define arbitrary keyboard shortcuts in Firefox, including overriding some of the already built-in shortcuts (such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to close a tab).

How can I accomplish this?  I've found a few plug-ins that add specific additional short cuts, but none that are fully editable.  I also couldn't find anything in any of the options menu to do so, though I'd be surprised if this was a feature that was built-in.

For reference (if needed):
Firefox 3.0.12
CentOS 5.2

Answer (score 1):

[Use the Keyconfig addon](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994)

[This extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/1537) will provide core functions for keyboard operation.

- Scrolling
- Tab Focusing
- Frame Focusing
- Finding
- Copy URL
- Clear HTTP Auth

Combining with keyconfig extension, you can set any shortcut key to these functions simply. 
If you operate Firefox by keyboard mainly, this extension will help you.

[image]

Comment: Is that first link right?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [AutoHotKey](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=5173) in combination with Wine, you can macro whatever shortcut you want!

> AutoHotkey is a free, open-source
>   utility for Windows. Automate almost
>   anything by sending keystrokes and
>   mouse clicks. You can write a mouse or
>   keyboard macros by hand or use the
>   macro recorder. Create hotkeys for
>   keyboard, joystick, and mouse.
>   Virtually any key, button, or
>   combination can become a hotkey.
>   Create custom data-entry forms, user
>   interfaces, and menu bars. Convert any
>   script into an EXE file that can be
>   run on computers that don't have
>   AutoHotkey installed.