# Firefox (3.5) does not provide any method of customizing keyboard shortcuts

Tags: browser-addons, firefox

["Firefox (3.5) does not provide any method of customizing keyboard shortcuts."](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Keyboard+shortcuts)

I just upgraded from Firefox 3.0 to Firefox 3.5 and got most of my customizations working again.

My question is, how do I customize a single, simple keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+Shift+H --> Home Page, instead of Show History).

I saw this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/18605/customizing-firefox-shortcuts) but it refers to Firefox 3.0. I even downloaded keyconfig, unzipped it, [modifed install.rdf](http://ubuntuguide.net/customize-firefox-35-shortcut-keys-with-keyconfig) and installed it but I for some reason, I still cannot add new keys (I click Add New Key and nothing happens.)

This is exactly why I always delay upgrading FF. :-(

BEGIN SARCASM Hurray, a new version of Firefox! Hurray, a day of fiddling to get things back exactly how they were yesterday! END SARCASM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a Firefox 3.5 compatible version [here](http://mozilla.dorando.at/keyconfig.xpi).

Answer (score 1):

You could try `AutoHotKey`!

```
#IfWinActive, Mozilla Firefox
^+H::!{Home}
#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Vimperator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4891), a plugin which customizes Firefox's keyboard commands to act just like VI!

It sounds crazy, but allows you to quickly navigate most websites with no mouse.